# Why Chrome hanging

Tags: google-chrome

I realize this is a very general question but we are wondering if anyone has any suggestions in trying to troubleshoot why Chrome hangs *sometimes* when rendering certain pages on our site. It's intermittent. We've tried checking out all the plug-ins, disabling, etc. Just can't come to any rhyme or reason why it's happening. Any pointers on how to troubleshoot and resolve would be appreciated. It's an ASP.NET MVC site. Internet Explorer has no issue. Thanks.

Comment: What site? What's on it? You need to give people something to go on here. Generally speaking, you might want to open up the Chrome Inspect tab and see what's happening.

Comment: Have you looked at what javascript you are running?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work that way. This isn't a site for "Here's a vague description of a problem I'm having. Can you give me a list of all of the possible causes for that problem?" questions. This site is for *specific* questions that can be somewhat definitively answered, not a speculation and guesswork site.

Comment: I realize it's very general and not of the substance I usually post. I prefixed my post with that. We've spent weeks working on this problem. I'm not asking for all the possible causes. I'm only trying to tap the user base to see if there's some tool / method I should try that might get me to something of substance. At the moment we haven't a clue what's causing the issue - hence the generality.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it isn't going to be possible for someone to answer your problem for you, but if you can invest a two or three hours in the problem then you may well be able to solve it yourself.

As the issue appears in Chrome then you may be interested in the free ["Discover DevTools" course](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools) run by Codeschool and sponsored by Google (you have to register in order to follow the course, but it is free).

I suspect that the issue will turn out to be related to a memory leak where large numbers of elements are being added to and removed from the DOM using JavaScript, or the same element(s) are being added and removed multiple times. The course specifically covers "Memory Profiling" using Chrome Dev Tools, as well as the specific problem of memory leaks - the cause of them and how to resolve them.

If it is a memory leak, then the issue will closely correlate with the amount of time the page is open within the browser, especially if it is a result of one or more elements being frequently added and removed as a result of user interaction.

Comment: It is on page load so no user interaction has occurred yet. Don't think it's due to lots of code adding and removing elements.

Comment: This being the case you will definitely want to make use of the Developer Tools within Chrome to see what is going on.

Comment: The "Network" tab may be relevant if content is blocking loading (JavaScript blocks downloading other assets and further building the DOM in case it needs to do a Document.Write). It may also be worth following the many tutorials on JavaScript loading optimisation, placing the scripts at the bottom of the page for example, and certainly after stylesheet references.

Comment: Thanks for the tip pwdst. Chrome's Audit feature is reporting the same too - to load external CSS before external JS - we'll give that a go